# Authentication with different fields or properties symfony2

Tags: security, symfony

I am trying to create an authentication system with different property not like we have seen often "last_username" referring to username column in database. I would like to refer another property , named code. Just one input type integer. And when submit user to be directed to the protected route. When i do that says error variable code does not exist. Thank you

Comment: dear chronos, please give us SO-People more information. What error do you get? What do you want excactly in one sentence?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am saying that instead of username and password, i want to use just one input field or referring to another column in database.  I have a table user with username and password columns. i dont want that user to login in application using these two fileds. I want user to use different column. let say email since you dont understand column code or number